# Twilio Redirecting the wrong call when using CallSid and trying to update live call

Tags: twilio

So here's the logic of what I am working on:

1. Someone calls my Twilio Number I use the dial twiml to forward to a cell phone
2. I use gather and play a whisper to the operator answering the phone (so his cell phone).
3. The operator has a choice - press 1 to accept, press 2 (transfers to
   a different agent).

step 3 is where I am having trouble I am using the code below:

```
$call = $twilio->calls($CallSid)
           ->update([
                        "method" => "POST",
                        "url" => "http:www.example.com/directcall.php"
                    ]
           );
```

Here's the problem it is modifying the call but it's redirecting the operators phone number instead of the person who is calling in. So the operator is getting redirected to the other operator and the customer is being hung up on. I tried using the parentcallsid too but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

so just to be clear I want the flow to work like this:

Customer calls phone number -> redirects to designated operator -> if designated operator presses 2 it redirects the customer to operator 2 and disconnects operator 1 from the call. Is this possible?

Thanks for the help, I greatly appreciate it.

**UPDATE PLEASE FIND THE CODE SAMPLES BELOW**

**Index.php**

```php
<?php
include ("config.php");
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

$response = new VoiceResponse();


$twilionumber = ltrim($_POST['To'], '+');
$callernumber=ltrim($_POST['From'], '+');

createCall($phonenumbertouse,$response,$twilionumber);




echo $response;





function createCall($phonenumbertouse,$response,$twilionumber) {
 

$dial = $response->dial('',['timeout' => '30']); 



    $dial->number($phonenumbertouse, ['action' => "http://example.com/whisper.php",'method' => 'GET']);  
  
}
```

**WHISPER.PHP**

```php
<?php
include ("config.php");

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

$response = new VoiceResponse();


$gather = $response->gather(['action' => "http://example.com/route.php",
    'method' => 'GET']);
$gather->say($whisper, ['voice' => 'woman', 'language' => 'en-US']);

echo $response;

?>
```

**route.php**

```php
<?php
include ("config.php");
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$response = new VoiceResponse();
$keyedInput=$_REQUEST['Digits'];
$mycallsid=$_REQUEST['ParentCallSid'];



if ($keyedInput == 1){
     $response->say('connecting the call');
}
elseif ($keyedInput == 2){
    $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
    $call = $twilio->calls($mycallsid)
                   ->update([
                                "method" => "POST",
                                "url" => "http://example.com/redirect.php"
                            ]
                   );







}


elseif  ($keyedInput == 3){
        $response->say('you selected 3');

}
else  { 
        $response->say('Sorry, I don\'t understand that choice.');
        
    }
 
 
 echo $response;


?>
```

**Redirect.php **

```php
<?php
include ("config.php");
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;


$response = new VoiceResponse();


$dial = $response->dial('+14151234567',['timeout' => '30']); 

echo $response;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your issue here is that you are using the wrong `CallSid` to update.

In this case there are two `CallSid`s at play. When your user dials in to your Twilio number, that call between the user and Twilio has one `CallSid`. Then, when Twilio creates an outbound call to the operator, that call has a different `CallSid`.

In your application, when you get the `<Gather>` response from the operator, the `CallSid` being sent to your endpoint is the `CallSid` of the operator's call leg. Instead, you need to find the `CallSid` of the original call.

You should find that the [`ParentCallSid` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters) is sent to the webhook endpoint as well. That `ParentCallSid` is the original inbound call's Sid and is what you should use to redirect the caller to another operator.

**Edit**

OK, so I had a go at building this. I don't normally work in PHP, so I wrote this in Node.js (as Twilio Functions). I got it to work and the answer still seems to me to be "use the `ParentCallSid`, so hopefully it gives you some idea where you might have gone wrong.

##### The incoming call

This makes an outbound call to my cell phone number, with a `url` set to make the whisper to me when I answer the call.

```js
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  const dial = twiml.dial();
  dial.number({ url: "/whisper" }, MY_CELL_PHONE_NUMBER);
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial><Number url="/whisper">MY_CELL_PHONE_NUMBER</Number></Dial>
</Response>
```

##### The whisper

This returns a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) spoken to the person answering the cell phone number. It offers a choice, dial "1" to connect or "2" to hang up, triggering the original caller to dial to another number.

```js
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  const gather = twiml.gather({ digits: 1, action: "/after-whisper" });
  gather.say("Dial 1 to connect, dial 2 to hang up.");
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

```xml
<Response>
  <Gather action="/after-whisper" digits="1">
    <Say>Dial 1 to connect, dial 2 to hang up.</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

##### The Gather action "/after-whisper"

This checks the `Digits` parameter. If it is "1" it immediately calls back with an empty response, signalling the end of the whisper and leading the call to connect with the original caller.

If the `Digits` parameter is not "1" then we initialise a Twilio client and make a request to the API to update the call with the sid `ParentCallSid` to a new URL. Once that is complete we return TwiML that says to [`<Hangup>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup) the whisper call (which wasn't strictly necessary, but I like the intention).

```js
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  if (event.Digits === "1") {
    callback(null, twiml);
  } else {
    const client = context.getTwilioClient();
    try {
      // Update the parent call with a new URL.
      await client.calls(event.ParentCallSid).update({
        url: URL_TO_NEXT_TWIML,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    twiml.hangup();
    callback(null, twiml);
  }
};
```

##### The next TwiML

This is the endpoint that the `url` above relates to, when it gets the callback it just returns a `<Dial>` to another number, though it could include another whisper and go round this loop again if desired.

```js
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  twiml.dial(NEXT_NUMBER_TO_DIAL);
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial>NEXT_NUMBER_TO_DIAL</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: So I tried using the parent call sid before but it just returns an empty body. I checked and it is the correct Sid for the original call but when I use the code $call = $twilio->calls($parentCallSid)
           ->update([
                        "method" => "POST",
                        "url" => "http:www.example.com/directcall.php"
                    ]
           );     It just returns an empty response. Which causes an application error. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you fetch the parent call from its Sid? Or if you list calls by that parent Sid?

Comment: The logs show me that the call does get to the dial on the original call so it's doing something but it just hangs up both lines which is confusing. When I use the regular CallSid the dial works fine, but when I use the parentcallsid it just hangs up.

my example code:
'
$mycallsid=$_REQUEST['ParentCallSid'];

'$call = $twilio->calls("$mycallsid")
               ->update([
                            "method" => "POST",
                            "url" => "http://example.com/redirect.php"
                        ]
               );'

in redirect.php I use a voice response to dial

Comment: So it redirects to a response like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial timeout="30">14151234567</Dial>
</Response>

I am not sure, it's possible I am using the wrong response or something. But, it's strange that it works perfect for the callsid but not the parent callsid.

Comment: I've edited my answer and provided some example code, which, while written in JS, worked for me. Hopefully it might be able to tell you where you have gone wrong. If not, perhaps you can share a bit more of your code, particularly the entire code where you update the parent call.

Comment: Hi Phil, I really appreciate your help on this. I added all my code to the post above, it's weird because when I follow the trail inside twilio it looks like it is getting to the dial twiml part but it just hangs up the call on person A who called in and person B and never connects to person C. Thanks again for all the help. In short, when the person who answers press 2 it should forward the call.

Comment: I think I've got it! In your `route.php` you are checking `$keyedInput` against integers, but as this is input that technically could be anything, the values in `$_REQUEST` are likely strings. Try `$keyedInput == "1"` instead.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks so much. I tried it but unfortunately it's the same result, just a hang up. When I use `CallSid` it works by transferring b to c but `ParentCallSid` just hangs up on both sides still.

Comment: That's still weird! I just noticed another thing, your code shows you using the `action` attribute on the `<Number>` but to perform a whisper you should use the [`url` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url). I'm not sure that will fix it, but it's best to clear that sort of thing up. What happens if you try to fetch the parent call after the gather? `$call = $twilio->calls($mycallsid)]->fetch();` Does that request work?

Comment: Hi, so I fixed the action url attribute, it's still functioning the same. I also added the line above but it seems to be throwing this error?
`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\CallList as array`

I added it to the end of route.php right below echo $response;

thanks again

Comment: So I got `print($call->to);` `print($call->from);` working and it shows the right stuff. In the logs I can also see the parentcall was sent to the <dial> verb so it looks like it is working as intended but it still just drops both sides f the call.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck then. Honestly, the code I wrote that's in my answer above worked. Your code doesn't seem that different. You do have a timeout on the first `<Dial>` could that be kicking in before your operator denies the call? Just to be absolutely sure, are your responses `Content-Type: text/xml`? Can you try adding a specific `<Hangup>` to your whisper when the operator dials 2?

Comment: Hi Phil, I thought I would let you know I got it figured out. Apparently I had to enable advanced sip within the account. I did that and it worked perfect. If anyone else is stuck definitely try that. Thanks for your help throughout this process.

Comment: Glad you have things sorted now!